# Repeat calls to shell command, capture stdout via pipe

Tags: c++, pipe, exec, fork, dup2

I'm trying to get a C++ application on Linux to regularly check for the presence of a bluetooth device.
 - I can do this easily via hcitool on the command line, and it works reliably.
 - I can do it in my application multiple times, if I leave stdout alone, and it works.
 - I can get the stdout into my application, but it seems to go out-of-sync with the output from the hcitool.

Here's what I have written so far:

```
std::string checkBluetoothPresence(std::string searchForMAC)
{
    int pipeOut[2];
    pid_t pid;
    char btRtnVal[255] = "";

    pipe2(pipeOut, O_CLOEXEC);      // Both threads will share a pipe - input from child, output to parent
    switch(pid=fork())
    {
    case -1:    cout << "fork failed" << endl;
                exit(-1);
    case 0:     // Child thread
                close(1);               // Close stdout
                close(pipeOut[0]);      // Close the output end of pipeOut
                dup2(pipeOut[1], 1);    // Redirect stdout to pipeOut input
                close(pipeOut[1]);
                execl("/usr/bin/hcitool", "hcitool", "name", searchForMAC.c_str(), (char*)NULL);
    default:    // Parent thread
                close(0);               // Close stdin
                close(pipeOut[1]);      // Close the input to pipeOut
                dup2(pipeOut[0], 0);    // Redirect stdin to the pipeOut output
                close(pipeOut[0]);
                waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
                cin.getline(btRtnVal, sizeof(btRtnVal)-1);
    }
    return btRtnVal;

}
```

Basically, as it stands it will get the name of my bluetooth device correctly if it is detected, and return it.  That will work multiple times in a row (my main() function calls this every 15 seconds).  If I then turn bluetooth off on my device, it returns an empty string (which is what I want).  After that point though, if I turn bluetooth back on again, it never works again.  It *should* detect it - it works on the command line, but not here.  I've tried this with all of the pipe / dup2 / close commands removed, and it works perfectly (via stdout).  So I assume my problem lies with my pipe / dup2 / close commands somewhere.  I've tried a lot of variations (this is just the latest), but can't get it to work.

I suspect it's something to do with the redirecting of stdout not being correctly reset somewhere, but I've read and tried dozens of combinations I've found online and can't get any to work.  Any suggestions would be really appreciated - this has been driving me mad for hours!

Maybe the basic question is: does anyone have a good, comprehensive example of redirecting the output from a shell command, reading it, then resetting everything so that when I call the same command a few seconds later it still works?

Comment: My guesws, but it really is just a guess, is that when you get "empty string", it results in an error (end of file, or similar), which you need to reset with `cin.clear()` before you can read correctly from the stream again.

Comment: Mats, thank you - I added cin.clear() just before waitpid and that's fixed it.  Easy when you know how - was up half of the night trying to sort that one!

Answer (score 0):

Now answered - the problem was as Mats Petersson pointed out in the comments, I was simply missing a cin.clear() in the parent thread.  Once the first one failed, the EOF flag was raised which I guess I'd assumed would have been reset automatically when the thread was created the next time around.